# How powerful is x3d for making animations?

Tags: python, animation, x3d

I want to make a rotating drillbit animation that shows the complete process of drilling.

I am not really sure that it can be done using [x3d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D). How good is x3d (along with python scripting, maybe) to make such animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not really sure that it can be
>   done using x3d. How good is x3d (along
>   with python scripting, maybe) to make
>   such animations?

If you are running a modern - [developer version browser](http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=9), then you can visit my home page mid-awe.com to see what I did with X3DOM. The animation was very simple with the Flux/Vivaty studio tool and X3DOM are really all you need after the 3D model.

I recommend Wings3D or Blender 2.5 to generate the VRML/X3D. Then import X3D -> Vivaty Studio for animation. Finally, export X3D non-compressed. 
Open the X3D (XML) copy contents to the conversion tool specified on the X3DOM website.

(I tried to provide all of the links but this site stopped me - for good or bad you'll have to search for the tools I suggested)